# Python Plotly Sankey Graph not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, sankey-diagram

Was wondering if anyone can help figure out why this Sankey diagram is not working. I am pretty sure I followed the proper syntax and conventions to use the module. Been banging my head on the table because of this.

```
import plotly.offline

data_trace = {'domain': {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    'height': 772,
    'link': {'label': ['EM', 'GWF9C51E', 'GWF9C511', 'GWF9C51E Sensor Set',
                                'GWF9C511 Sensor Set'],
             'source': [0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 2],
             'target': [1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4],
             'value': [40, 76, 29, 86, 30, 75, 41, 65]},
    'node': {'color': ['blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green', 'green'],
             'label': ['EM', 'GWF9C51E', 'GWF9C511', 'GWF9C51E Sensor Set',
                      'GWF9C511 Sensor Set'],
             'line': {'color': 'black', 'width': 0.5},
             'pad': 15,
             'thickness': 15},
             'orientation': 'h',
             'type': 'sankey',
             'valueformat': '.3s',
             'valuesuffix': 'pkts',
             'width': 1118}
layout =  dict(
    title = "Testing Sankey",
    font = dict(
    size = 10
    )

fig = dict(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, validate=False)
```

Comment: Can you read this article, the problem is with your data, [read more](https://community.plot.ly/t/sankey-diagram-appearing-as-blank/4959/2)

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Ill have to think of another way to represent Source: 0 -> Target: 1 and Source: 1 -> Target: 0. Probably just separate out to send/recieve nodes.

Comment: You're welcome, Post the solution as the answer to your question once you figure it out also, there is not much detail on sankey charts! Thanks!

Comment: Will do! Got it working now. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry again, you need to give the green tick to close your answer :)

Comment: It says I have to wait until tomorrow before I can do that.

Comment: Completely forgot about this. I went ahead and clicked the green checkmark.

Comment: Good! No problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
         'source': [1, 3],
         'target': [3, 1]
```

You cant have the sources and target play double roles ie: node 1 is both a source and a target.

Depending on your use case, you might have to split it up.

For mine, this is about a networking product so I split up my nodes to 'RX' and 'TX' so I don't double up the source/target data list.