# Sankey diagrams only support acyclic graphs - error message I get

Tags: python, sankey-diagram

So I'm trying to generate a snakey diagram from this dataframe :

```
    a   b   v
0   0   0   1
1   0   2   1
2   0   3   2
3   1   0   1
4   1   1   1
5   1   2   2
6   1   3   2
7   2   0   1
8   2   1   3
9   3   0   1
10  3   1   2
11  3   3   1
12  3   4   1
13  3   5   1
14  4   3   1
15  5   2   1
```

here's my code :

```
import holoviews as hv
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as pex

hv.extension('bokeh')

hv.Sankey(df_test2, kdims=["a","b"], vdims=["v"])
```

I get this message error : Sankey diagrams only support acyclic graphs.
I don't really understand why it's not working !

Answer (score 1):

As mozway [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68952295/6155968), the problem is that your data includes cyclic links. These are not supported by Sankey diagram function in `holoviews`.
However, you can plot Sankey diagram with cyclic elements using `plotly` (e.g. following this [tutorial](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#basic-sankey-diagram)).

Comment: I was able to identify self-loops (ie. a-> a) and direct recursive cycles (ie. a-> b, b -> a) but does anyone know how to identify and remove more complicated recursive cycles (ie. a -> b -> c -> d -> a)?

Comment: When I use plotly to generate a sankey diagram, it produces no error and no image :(
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880668/5986651 So not sure what @Kamil is talking about. :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory. You cannot draw the plot as some keys are inducing a cycle. For instance the first row would give `0->0->0->0->(…)`, which is impossible. Similarly, rows 1 and 7 give `0->2->0->2->(…)`. You have to make sure that elements in `b` cannot make loops by coming back through `a`.

From your dataset, here is a working example (picked 3 rows without recursionà:

```
hv.Sankey(df.iloc[1:4], kdims=["a","b"], vdims=["v"])
```

Comment: I understand the problem of cycles being induces. However, what if the columns `a` and `b` of the OP represent different things. `a` could be the number of children in a family and `b` could be the number of pets in the family. How would one go about visualizing that relationship in a Sankey diagram with holoviews?